# Thread 1: Exc_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=xxx-xxxx)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I'm new to IOS dev and getting the following Thread 1: Exc_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=someaddress) when the getter is called from my XCtest:

```
var token:AccessToken?{
    set{ self.token = newValue }
    get{ return self.token }
} 

class AccessToken{
   var access_token:String
   var token_type:String

   init(access_token: String,token_type: String){
       self.access_token = access_token
       self.token_type = token_type
   } 
}


request.token! = AccessToken(access_token: "accessToken", token_type: "Bearer")
```

I'm figuring that I might be using the getter incorrectly however the compiler is not catching the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is an infinite loop in the setter of `token` which calls itself permanently.

Getter and setter are implicitly synthesized, just declare the variable.

```
var token : AccessToken?
```

Comment: So I don't need to use getters and setters on optionals?

Comment: Yes, you don't need them unless the values are related to other variables.